# Fade out after div content has been shown using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a notification on button click. The button click actually checks for email validation. I know to show a div with content with the error message. However, I would like to fade out the error message, lets say after 5 seconds. I would like to achieve it using CSS.

Below is my attempt, it just hides everything.

```css
#signup-response {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="signup-response">Thank you</div>
```

Comment: You could use the css3 animation keyframes to achieve your goal. Its not exactly cross browser friendly though.

Comment: Could you please show an example? I think for an error message cross browser friendly is not that important. Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `animation`  **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9kYa/)**.

Set the `animation-delay` to the time you want. Make sure you use `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to stop the animation.

```
#signup-response{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin-top: 20px;

     animation:signup-response 0.5s 1;
    -webkit-animation:signup-response 0.5s 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    animation-delay:2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

} 

@keyframes signup-response{
    from {opacity :1;}
    to {opacity :0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes signup-response{
    from {opacity :1;}
    to {opacity :0;}
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Using css3 keyframe animation:

(You'll probably want to add `-webkit-` `-moz-`, `-ms-`, and `-o-` prefixes on the `animation` and `animation-delay` properties inside `.error-message` and on the `keyframes` to support older browsers.)

```css
.error-message {
    animation: fadeOut 2s forwards;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="error-message">
    <p>Some random text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice simple solution. One small thing: there should be no property `forwards` on `-webkit-animation-delay: 5s forwards;`. Maybe this was a cut-and-paste issue from `animation`?

Comment: Good catch. I think I actually just missed the line to put forwards on. It should be `animation: fadeOut 2s forwards;` instead of `animation: fadeOut 2s;` I guess I'll take the time to just insert a code snippet and replace what was there too.

Answer (score 3):

cross browser hack (instead of using css3 animation keyframes):

```
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,1,1.0,0);}
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,1,1.0,0);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp

Comment: added a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp)