# CSS3 - Make div disappear after delay

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am working in a css code for my project and I got to animate a div only using css3 animations. I tried generating below code using some tools available in web and produced a shake effect animation.

```css
div.error {
    background-color: #E49F5C;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 99999;
    animation: animationFrames linear 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames linear 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation: animationFrames linear 1s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation: animationFrames linear 1s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation: animationFrames linear 1s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  
}
@keyframes animationFrames{
  0% {
    transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
  10% {
    transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  20% {
    transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  30% {
    transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  40% {
    transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  50% {
    transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  60% {
    transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  70% {
    transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  80% {
    transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  90% {
    transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  100% {
    transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animationFrames{
  0% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
  10% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  20% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  30% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  90% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {
    -o-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
  10% {
    -o-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  20% {
    -o-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  30% {
    -o-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  40% {
    -o-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  60% {
    -o-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  70% {
    -o-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  80% {
    -o-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  90% {
    -o-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
  10% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  20% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  30% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  40% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  60% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  70% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  80% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(10px,0px)  ;
  }
  90% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(-10px,0px)  ;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="error fadeInRight" id="errorbox">Please enter title</div>
```

**Update:** I am using this div to show the server side php form validation error message.
Now my question is how to make this div display for 5 seconds and disappear with a fade out effect after executing the above animation part. This final animation should be only using css3 again. Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fade out after div content has been shown using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388402/fade-out-after-div-content-has-been-shown-using-css)

Comment: @Michael_B: I would disagree there. The answer there is using animation delays, which isn't what the OP is actually looking for. I'm sure there could be a dupe out there, but I'm too lazy to find one right now

Comment: @jbutler483, the referenced dupe seems tailor made for this request. It even asks for a 5 second fade out of a validation error message, just like this question. It may not be an exact duplicate, but I think the answers there are relevant here.

Comment: @Michael_B: and yet us in an animation-delay will not allow you to shake the message, and hence will not help the OP?

Comment: @jbutler483, I'm not committed to the dupe. Hence the term *possible duplicate*. Your disagreement is noted, and this question may not be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without some of the added fancy stuff, I'll show you how you **could** design this.

Since an element can only have one animation defined, you'll have to place the animation for the delay into the 'shake' effect as well. For example, a timeline could be:

- shake left
- shake right
- shake left
- shake right
- stay still
- fade

Seeing as you want the fade after 5 seconds, you're going to have to time the length of your animation to 6 seconds, as an example.

```css
div {
  -webkit-animation: error 6s forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  background: lightgray;
}
@-webkit-keyframes error {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  5% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  15% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>ERROR
  <br/>Code: 150054
  <br/>Message: You're PC is about to burn up!
</div>
```

Comment: @krishna89: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Comment: I HAVE A WORD FOR YOU "AWESOME DEAR", THIS IS SOLUTION WHAT I WAS LOOKING. IT WORKS NICELY :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could relay in using animation-delay somehow, however it's way easier (and more supported) with jQuery:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#errorbox').fadeOut();
},5000);
```